# How can I retrieve the list of email addresses of all attendees of an event in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

How can I retrieve the list of email addresses of all attendees of an event in the Microsoft Outlook web interface? (without having to copy paste each email address one by one)

[image]